# Completeness of tests based on a monotone likelihood ratio family

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, complete-statistics

In "[Mathematical statistics: basic ideas and selected topics, Volume 1](http://books.google.com/books?id=wImDQgAACAAJ&dq=bickel%20doksum&hl=en&ei=tpaLTuqQCIbi0QHXyemKBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA)" by Bickle and Doksum,

**Theoreom 4.3.2.** Suppose $\{P_\theta : \theta \in \Theta \},\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}$, is a monotone likelihood ratio family in statistic $T(x)$, and suppose
the loss function $l(\theta, a)$ is "reasonable" in the sense mentioned later, 
then the class of tests of the form 
$$
\delta_t(x) = 1 \text{ if } T(x) > t; 
$$
$$
\delta_t(x) = 0 \text{ if } T(x) < t; 
$$
with $E \delta_t(X) = \alpha, 0 < \alpha < 1$, is complete.

**My questions:**

1. Does "the class of tests" mean $\{ \delta_t, t \in \mathbb{R}\}$?
2. In "$E \delta_t(X) = \alpha,
   0 < \alpha < 1$":

   (1) what is the distribution that the expectation is taken  relative to? Is the expectation taken relative     to any $\theta \in \Theta$?

   (2) what does $\alpha$ mean? Is it the significance level of the testing, or is it some constant that is same for all $\theta \in \Theta$ and all $t \in \mathbb{R}$?
3. Does the theorem only apply to testing of the form $H: \theta \leq
       \theta_0$ versus $K: \theta >     \theta_0$, not to the more general
   form $H: \theta \in \Theta_1$ versus $K: \theta \in
           \Theta_2$? If yes, possible to modify the theorem to accommodate the more general form of testing ?

**Note:** the book is not free of typos, so let's not rule out this possibility.
If there are other references with the same/similar statements, please don't hesitate to mention them. 
Thanks and regards!

---

**Concepts and conditions used in the theorem:**

1. **Definition 4.3.2.** The family of models $\{P_\theta: \theta \in \Theta \}$ with $\Theta \subset \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *a monotone
   likelihood ratio (MLR) family in statistic $T(x)$*, if for $\theta_1
       < \theta_2$ the distributions $P_{\theta_1}$ and $P_{\theta_2}$ are
   distinct and the ratio $p(x, \theta_2)/p(x, \theta_1)$ is an
   increasing function of $T(x)$.
2. When testing $H: \theta \leq \theta_0$ versus $K: \theta >
       \theta_0$, a *reasonable* class of loss functions are those that
   satisfy $$ l(\theta,1) > l(\theta,0) \text{ for } \theta <
       \theta_0 $$ $$ l(\theta,1)<l(\theta,0) \text{ for } \theta >
       \theta_0. $$
   where as arguments to the loss functions, $1$ means rejecting $H$, and $0$ means accepting $H$.
3. The class $D$ of decision procedures is said to be *complete* if for
   any decision rule $\phi \notin D$, there exists $\delta \in D$ such
   that $$ R(\theta, \delta) \leq R(\theta, \phi) \text{ for all }
       \theta \in \Theta, $$ where $R(\theta, \delta)$ measures the
   expected risk of the rule $\delta$ for $\theta \in \Theta$.  That
   is, if the model is correct and loss function is appropriate, then
   any procedure not  in the complete class can be matched or improved
   at all $\theta \in \Theta$ by one in the complete class. Thus, it
   isn't worthwhile to look outside of complete classes. In testing, the decision procedures are test functions.